# Trying to make my dropdown box work without having to click a button

Tags: php, button, dropdown

I am developing a website that requires a person to select a product from a dropdown box. It goes like this. Click on the box and the list of items "dropdown". (The list is generated from a mysql query) Select an item. The list disappears leaving the selected item viewable in the box. click on the 'enter' button and the selected item is now the topic of the page. All that works wonderfully. What I want to happen is for the user to select the item in the dropdown list and then have that item become the topic of page without clicking on a button. So, the button would disappear altogether. I've spent several hours looking at JavaScript examples without much luck. I may have found what I needed but not known it because I'm kinda new at this. I need help. Here is the code I am using that is very functional as described above. Thank you for the help.

```
        <!-- Dropdown product selection -->
    <?php    
            $sql4 = $pdo->query 
                (
                    "SELECT product FROM product WHERE sub_category = '$sub_category' Order by product"
                );
            
        // output data of each row
            while($row = $sql4->fetch()) {
                $menu .= '<option value="'
                        . $row['product'] 
                        .'">' 
                        . $row['product']
                        . "</option>";
                }

                echo $menu;
        // disconnect from the database                        
           $pdo = null; 
        ?>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name= "zipcode" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['zipcode']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value = "Enter">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Html

```
<form id="s_product" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <select id="product" name="product">
     (Your <option>)
  </select>
</form>
```

Js

```
<script>
document.getElementById("product").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("s_product").submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please always explain your solutions.  "Try this" answers are missed opportunities to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.